# mysqld high memory usage

Tags: mysql

Is this usage normal? Mysql isn't doing anything all the time but yet it has a high memory usage all the time.

[image: htop]

Comment: What do you mean with "high usage" ? CPU usage on all processes in your picture are around zero.

Comment: High memory usage

Comment: No, this is certainly not normal, not over a significant period. It looks like these are hanging queries. You may want to turn on the debugging log and see what threads are left hanging. Perhaps there is already something useful in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`.

Comment: i have mysql error log on. but the log is empty

Comment: it seems as if that is only the threads in htop. looks like this without them
https://i.imgur.com/4ZNING3.png